# "A positive influence on [the] circulation of blood"

Tags: meaning, articles, definite-articles

What is the difference in meaning between the following?

> - Habitual physical activity has a positive influence on circulation of blood.
> - Habitual physical activity has a positive influence on the circulation of blood.

Comment: What makes you assume there is any difference in meaning?

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, it is just natural for me to assume there would be a difference because the structures are different.  If you are being sarcastic,then that it not helpful at all.

Comment: The first example is not normal, but is used in certain registers, for example medical texts. In medical registers in particular, many definite articles are omitted.

Comment: Personally I would put a 'the' in front of both 'circulation' and 'blood'. It is not strictly essential in either case, but it sounds better to my native ear.

Comment: "Habitual physical activity has a positive influence on blood circulation."

Answer (score 1):

In this example, there is no difference in meaning.

The definite article *the* can be used or omitted with noncount nouns (https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/). *Circulation* in this example is a non-countable noun. If the sentence refers to blood circulation in a particular context, then the article *the* should be included. Otherwise, it may be omitted.

Here is an alternative sentence with identical meaning:
*Habitual physical activity has a positive influence on blood circulation.* Many English speakers would slightly prefer this wording because it eliminates the extra preposition (*of*).